# char** in function C and valgrind conditional jump erro

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, valgrind

First of all my question is C only, not C++. I've search on SO and google my problem but I think it comes from a lack of understanding of both valgrind and some pointer in function argument in C so if someone could kindly explain to me, I'll be very grateful.

Here is my code in the main. The function getOrder is just supposed to cut the string after the ';' and send the second part (here "on") back in the bu variable buffer.

```
char na[] = "2;on";
char* bu="on";

//This part Do conditionnal jump
getOrder(na, 4, &bu);

//This part Doesn't do conditionnal jump
//char copy[strlen(na)];
//strcpy(copy, na);

//bu=strtok(na,";");

bu[2]='\0';

printf("ending : %s\n",bu); //(<- this is the line 54 of the valgrind error)
```

And here is the getOrder function :

```
//TODO conditionnal jump here ! Only whn returning from the function
char* getOrder(char order[], int size, char* res[]){
int i=0;
char copy[size];
strcpy(copy, order);

printf("\nstr: %s\n", copy);
*res=strtok(copy,";");
printf("tok : %s\n", *res);
*res=strtok(NULL, ";");
printf("tok : %s\n", *res); 
printf("%d and order is %s\n",strcmp(*res, "on"), *res);

return *res;
}
```

What I don't understand is why, when I use the getOrder function, Valgrind complains about all of this :

```
==7072== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7072==    at 0x4E7EC15: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x400A0D: main (test.c:54)
==7072== 
==7072== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7072==    at 0x4EAEBC9: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x400A0D: main (test.c:54)
==7072== 
==7072== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7072==    at 0x4EAEBD7: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E7EBB5: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x400A0D: main (test.c:54)
==7072== 
==7072== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==7072==    at 0x4F25E90: __write_nocancel (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4EAE49C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4EAF948: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4EAEB5C: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E7EB55: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x4E88748: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.20.so)
==7072==    by 0x400A0D: main (test.c:54)
==7072==  Address 0x4022009 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7072==
```

But it doesn't when I use directly the same thing in the main. Basically those errors comes from the way I use the function getOrder (be it in the arguments, are the pointer I send) but I'm unable to find what is my mistake.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `res` end's up being a pointer to `copy`, and copy is deleted with the stack frame of `getOrder` function, since it's a local variable.

try this

```
//TODO conditionnal jump here ! Only whn returning from the function
char* getOrder(char order[], int size)
{
    int i=0;
    char copy[size];
    char *res;

    strcpy(copy, order);

    printf("\nstr: %s\n", copy);

    res = strtok(copy, ";");
    if (res == NULL) /* always check the return value from strtok */
        return NULL;
    printf("tok : %s\n", res);

    res = strtok(NULL, ";");
    if (res == NULL) /* always check the return value from strtok */
        return NULL;
    printf("tok : %s\n", res);
    printf("%d and order is %s\n", strcmp(res, "on"), res);

    return order + (res - copy);
}
```

and the `size` parameter in your `getOrder` call should be `5` not `4`, since there are `4` chracters + the terminating null byte `'\0'`.

```
char *na = "2;on";
char *bu;

//This part Do conditionnal jump
bu = getOrder(na, 5);

//This part Doesn't do conditionnal jump
//char copy[strlen(na)];
//strcpy(copy, na);

//bu=strtok(na,";");

//bu[2] = '\0';

if (bu != NULL)
    printf("ending : %s\n", bu); //(<- this is the line 54 of the valgrind error)
return 0;
```

Comment: Why is there a redundant check for `res` once you have already checked the return value? why not just return the pointer `res` from your function?

Comment: I have no idea why the check, let me fix it. I don't return `res` because as explained it would be pointing to `copy` which lives in the stack frame of `getOrder`.

Comment: Oddly the function find the good value for res but order + (copy - res) return nothing for now. But the valgrind error seems gone.

Comment: @Malc Ohhhh sorry, it was wrong, it has to be `res - copy`, it means advance `order` by the offset of `res` from `copy`, since `copy` is as copy of `order` it is the offset you need. But `res > copy`, and hence the value was negative.

Comment: The `na` variable is not changed in the end I just checked it so does that mean `return` makes a copy ? I though it would change na.

Comment: No return doesn't make a copy, `strtok` does change the input parameter but you copied it in `strcpy(copy, order)`. So return does not copy `na` you do. And since you work on a copy of `na`, `na` doesn't change, note that while you can change the characters in `na` you can't append charactres to it.

Comment: Does that means in the end `bu` and `na` point to the same "structure" but at different "places" ? You said it return an offset of order but `na` is unchanged at the end that is why I am confused. For example, if I replace the "o" by a "u" in `na`, would that be reflected onto `bu` ?

Answer (score 1):

`bu` is just read-only. You can't do something like this:

```
bu[2] = '\0';
```

This will crash.

Coming to your problem if you want to have your second part of your string is another array then it can be done like this without the need of a function.

PS: `strtok()` will modify the actual string passed so it would be better to keep a copy of it and pass the copy.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char na[]="2;on";
    char bu[3];
    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(na,";");
    if(tok != NULL)
    printf("%s\n",tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL,";");
    if(tok != NULL)
    strcpy(bu,tok);
    printf("%s\n",bu);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually really want this as a function. The main is just here for testing purposes :)